# User can't change password using passwd (pam config)

Tags: opensuse, authentication, pam, non-root-user, passwd

I've created a new user and set a valid password (as root). The account is working and I can login locally/ssh etc.

However, when logged in as said user I can't change the password using `passwd`. I get a authentication token error after I type the Old password.

I believe it's my `pam` config but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any advice? OS is `openSUSE 12.1`

Pam.d config:

```
sbc:/etc/pam.d # cat passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth     include        common-auth
account  include        common-account
password include        common-password
session  include        common-session

sbc:/etc/pam.d # cat common-auth
#%PAM-1.0
#
# This file is autogenerated by pam-config. All changes
# will be overwritten.
#
# Authentication-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.). The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
auth    required        pam_env.so
auth    [success=2]     pam_unix2.so
auth    required        pam_script.so   bad     log=0
auth    requisite       pam_deny.so
auth    required        pam_script.so   good    log=0

sbc:/etc/pam.d # cat common-account
#%PAM-1.0
#
# This file is autogenerated by pam-config. All changes
# will be overwritten.
#
# Account-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the accountorization modules that define
# the central access policy for use on the system.  The default is to
# only deny service to users whose accounts are expired.
#
account required        pam_unix2.so

sbc:/etc/pam.d # cat common-password
#%PAM-1.0
#
# This file is autogenerated by pam-config. All changes
# will be overwritten.
#
# Password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define  the services to be
# used to change user passwords.
#
password        requisite       pam_pwcheck.so  debug nullok cracklib maxlen=128 minlen=8 retry=3 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 remember=12 enforce_for_root
password        required        pam_unix2.so    use_authtok nullok

sbc:/etc/pam.d # cat common-session
#%PAM-1.0
#
# This file is autogenerated by pam-config. All changes
# will be overwritten.
#
# Session-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of sessions of *any* kind (both interactive and
# non-interactive
#
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_unix2.so
session optional        pam_umask.so
session optional        pam_systemd.so
```

Comment: Did you generate that with `pam-config` or were you fiddling manually with the PAM rules? (If manually fiddling, you can debug with `auth required pam_echo about to do X` type statements to see what lines are consulted though this requires care around `[success=2]` skips...)

Comment: Yeah I'm manually changing the rules by editing the pam.d files. I shall give he echo option a try and hopefully pinpoint where I'm going wrong! Thank you. Is using pam-config the better option? I was weary of doing it that way as the config files had already been modified from the system generated ones.

Comment: I've (almost) always let the system configure the PAM stuff automagically as the PAM lines are a) complicated and b) easy to break.